Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method | Flutter Error
Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method | When i type anything and press done or close my keypad ,
its say Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method and wipe the added text . It should not wipe automatically

Declaring a TextEditingController with-in the build method can indeed lead to the Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method error in Flutter.
Video Guide : HERE
You can find solution of flutter errors here : PWH SERVICES YT Channel
Try to declare outside build :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: _textController,
      // ... other properties
    );
  }
}


Yes it works - Thank you
